# PHP Can write image to file in in public folder but not in subfolder

Tags: php, permissions, gd

I'm trying to write a gd image to disk using:

```
imagejpeg($gdimage, dirname(__FILE__) . $path . $fileName);
```

- If I set `$path = '/public/'` the image is created.
- If a set `$path = '/public/images/'` I get this warning and the image is not created:

  Warning: imagejpeg(): Unable to open    '/Users/david/Documents/Developer/NetbeansProjects/aem.davidcasillas.es/public/images/498x282_v1_Golf-LaLlorea.jpg' for writing: No such file or directory in /Users/david/Documents/Developer/Netbeans Projects/aem.davidcasillas.es/ModuloGijon.php on line 943

Permisions are set as:

- public folder: `drwxr-xr-x  77 david  admin   2618 24 abr 12:58 public`
- images folder: `drwxr-xr-x  6 david  admin    204 24 abr 10:38 images`

So I see no reason why I canot create the image in the images folder.
I have tried other subfolders in public and I always get the same error.

Comment: The error is `No such file or directory`, are you sure `images` is a subdir of `public`? The ls output looks as if they are both in the same parent directory...

Comment: The ls output is just a copy of two different ls commands. Maybe this lead to confusion. images is a subdir of public.

Answer (score 0):

change the permission of subfolders to writable.

```
chmod -R 777 public
```

Comment: But why does it work in public folder with the same permissions?

Comment: check out this: [link](http://superuser.com/questions/264383/set-file-permissions-so-that-new-files-inherit-same-permissions). The folder has not inherited parent permission.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. I am working with Netbeans and set to copy the project from my Documents folder to the MAMP installation folder. I create the dir under the MAMP installation but not under my Documents folder project. If you check the warning path you will see it points to my Documents folder and not to /Applications/MAMP folder.